# Creating my first app, confused about main activity and fragments

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to this but am very interested in creating my first app.
I managed (somehow) to get the navigation drawer working within my application, mainly due to following a YouTube tutorial.

I have my main activity and 5 other fragment files, one of which is called the 'Home' fragment.
Whenever I press 'Home' on the navigation bar I want this to take the user to the main activity page, which is the page that boots currently when the user first opens the app.
So essentially I want a fragment to appear within the activity on the main screen.
I have no idea how to do this and have already tried looking at the fragment documentation and it confuses me.

Could anyone help please?

Summary:
1. Want to display fragment on home page
2. The only reason why I want to do this is everything I place on my main activity then appears on every single fragment page

Comment: Fragments are like (interactive) "stickers" on an Activity. You simply swap them. But they aren't Activities themselves. So simply replace your current Fragment with the "Home" one.

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]. And remove all but at least 2 Fragments until you understand how it works.

Comment: so at the moment in my activity main all I have is code that enables the navigation bar, thats it. I dont know how to link activity main to a fragment so it displays it. im using android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Comment: Also @NoiseGenerator, I dont have a current fragment. The page is just blank

Comment: You don't "link an Activity to a Fragment". Fragments are "glued" to Activities, then eventually "unglued" and replaced with other ones.

Comment: So if I open my activity main xml file, how do I tell it to display the 'fragment home' xml file on top of it?

Comment: You should actually search and follow a tutorial on how to use Fragments.

Comment: I did but I dont get it still. In tutorials they do things on their keyboard without explaining what they are doing, so I have no idea what they changed lol

Comment: Don't follow video tutorials. Prefer written ones. Anyway, SO is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

As **@Noise Generator** commented you just have to replace your fragment with Home fragment like this :-

If you only want to use the fragment as the top level content view of the activity, then

```
    Fragment newFragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, newFragment).commit();
```

other wise as **@Dheeraj Joshi** stated you have to create a resource and then replace it

```
    Fragment newFragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment).commit();
```

Comment: When you say "replace your fragment" I dont get it sadly. I have activity_main.xml and fragment_home.xml. What do I replace?

Comment: when they say replace your fragment this means,just replace one fragment with another

Comment: you have activity_main.xml and fragment_home.xml,you don't have to replace anything just place the fragment in the container of activity_main.xml

Comment: try replacing your fragment with first solution and see what happens if it fits your requirement then all good otherwise do as @Dheeraj Joshi commented

Comment: Ok - so what is a container

Comment: I looked at my xml code and I cannot see anything regarding a container

Comment: I do however have this:

  <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/flcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

Comment: A container is a view used to contain other views. Android offers a collection of view classes that act as containers for views. These container classes are called layouts, and as the name suggests, they decide the organization, size, and position of their children views.

Comment: @SW18 FrameLayout here in your code is the container

Comment: thanks for your answer. so how do I say to this activity file that I want to display a fragment inside of it? so when the app is opened the fragment is there automatically and straight away for the user

Comment: @SW18 Just use a fragment transaction in onCreate() method of your activity with the container in which you want to display the fragment,with the help of fragment manager,for ex see my last 5 lines of code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

To add a fragment into a Activity or FramentActivity it requires a Container. That container should be a "Framelayout", which can be included in xml or else you can use the default container for that like "android.R.id.content" to remove or replace a fragment in Activity.

**XML FILE**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/next" />
```

or with a fragment tag

```
<fragment 
android:name="com.samplefrag"
android:id="@+id/samplefrag"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

in fragment container you can add fragments dynamically with fragment transaction too ,like see below

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            HelloFragment hello = new HelloFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container, hello, "HELLO");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**UPDATE**

for your problem,
You want to display main activity when you press home button,so you can use Intent and send data with intent,then recieve that data into Main Activity and use fragment transaction according to it to display the fragment in your activity

Comment: Fragments also can directly be defined in the XML, though

Comment: I was talking about `<fragment` tags

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I am a mega noob and still don't understand.

Comment: What exactly do I need to update/add to my XML file? You inserted some code but Im unsure what it does :(

Comment: @SW18 like in the xml file just add a FrameLayout and then dynamically add a fragment to it using java code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm confused here, as you mention in the xml file to add a frame layout but also say to add java code... but we are talking about the xml file which is xml coding only no?

Comment: @SW18 frame layout is just an empty container we put using xml file,and by java code i mean that,you have to use fragment transaction in your activity code to fill that empty container with a fragment otherwise it will be empty,by java code means just to fill that frame layout using fragment transaction